# Server error trying to delete user in web console "permissions" view

Tags: google-app-engine

Not sure if this is the right place for this, forgive me if it isn't.
I also opened a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10744&thanks=10744&ts=1396030335

Steps to reproduce:

1) I go to appengine.google.com

2) I select one of the applications I have access to (either "qmaghomolog" or "qmagicobr2")

3) On the left navigation bar, I click on "Permissions" (under Administration)

4) I see myself listed with Role = Owner

5) I click the "Remove" button for another user

BUG: I get a new page that says only

```
Server Error
A server error has occurred.
(link) Return to Applications screen »
```

And no further information is given.

Please help :-)